# Unable to start embedded container with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

I have a springboot app that uses a database stored in SQL Express (works perfectly, `app.properties` below) , and I exported that database to SQL Server 2019, and now I'm facing **Error starting Tomcat context**. Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xxxl</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>xx</name>
    <description>xxx</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.11.RELEASE</version>

        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.32</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- db test -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.194</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.kerberos</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-kerberos-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.kerberos</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-kerberos-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <!--<version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/momentjs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>momentjs</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--WebJars-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-select</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datetimepicker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/datatables -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>js-cookie</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- auto reload-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- flying saucer pdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jtidy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
            <version>4aug2000r7-dev</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>

                <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</sonar.jdbc.url>
                <sonar.jdbc.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
                <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
                <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
                <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
                    <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
                    <targetJdk>1.8</targetJdk>

                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>/rulesets/braces.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Bean.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/generated/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <excludeRoots>
                        <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/</excludeRoot>
                    </excludeRoots>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.905</version>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>
                                xxx
                            </mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and here's my application.properties for SQLExpress

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:xxxx;databaseName=dbName;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

and here's my application.properties for SQL Server

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:xxxx;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=dazdzdzdzdzdz
spring.datasource.name=dbname

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried choosing one of `username and password` or `nativeAuthentication`? Integrated/native authentication uses the LDAP/Windows credentials of the executing process and shouldn't be mixed with SQL Login (username and password) authentication.

Comment: yes but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by removing the line :

```
spring.datasource.name=dbname
```

and putting the databaseName in the url link :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:y;databaseName=DBNAME;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication
```

Comment: done!  thanks  I forgot that I already answerd it !